# How to split a whole page in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is it possible to split the whole page in half and not just the current window in Vim?

In tmux you can do it by using split-window with a `-f` flag.

For example there have two windows (a), when you split horizontally in the right one, a new window appears at the bottom right (b).

What I want to do is split the whole page in half (c).

```
a.  ___________
   |1    |2    |
   |     |     |
   |     |     |
   |_____|_____|

b.  ___________
   |1    |2    |
   |     |_____|
   |     |3    |
   |_____|_____|

c.  ___________
   |1    |2    |
   |_____|_____|
   |3          |
   |___________|
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want (some more explanation / primitive drawing would be nice), but you can make a Vim window cover the whole width / height with the `CTRL-W` + (uppercase!) `K` / `J` / `H` / `L` commands.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I've added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good question.

With two vertical splits and a third horizontal split you can move the third split window to the bottom by using `ctrl + w` then `shift + j` to rotate the split window down and take the whole bottom as you are looking for in (c).